# DataGrid control that supports row details

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

I am looking for a free/pay component for .NET Windows Forms that let's be visualize (tabular) a single listing containing various types of data. I would also walcome a way to customize any of the built in .NET components to do the same thing.

I have a dataset comprised of 4 different types of data, which all implement a common interface. I can set the datasource of a DataGridView to be a list of the interface objects and I get a nice looking uniform grid just fine. However, what I want to do is be able to expand each row to view the actual datatype values of the underlying class.

Here is an example set of data:

```
public interface ICommonData {
    long ID {get;}
    DateTime Date {get;}
}

public class ClassA : ICommonData {
    public long ID {get;}
    public DateTime Date {get;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class ClassB : ICommonData {
    public long ID {get;}
    public DateTime Date {get;}
    public long SomeReferenceNumber {get;set;}
    public string SomeName {get;set;}
}
```

Using this data, I would bind the grid to a List that contained a mixture of ClassA and ClassB objects. What I need is the ability to expand any of the rows and see a record with all the fields of ClassA or ClassB depending on the data type bound to that row.

I know what I need is possible using the Microsoft WPF DataGrid object (with RowDetailSelector), but I'd rather not use WPF for this kind of thing if I don't have to. Another important note is, this is all read only. I do not need any way to edit any of this data. My use case is that I have library that is hooked to many different types of error log records, and I need a way to visualize all these different types of error records in one tabular format (while being able to see all the fields on all the different types of data).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any idea how this "mixture" shall look like? Everything tabular? Any idea how to visualize which rows are of type "ClassA" and which ones are of type "ClassB"?

Comment: For the main rows of the table, it would be straight table based on the ICommonData properties. When you expand a row, ideally what you would see is a sub-table layout with a single row showing all the columns of the actual ClassA or ClassB properties. Or at least give me a panel where I can lay out my own format for the data. That is how the WPF control works... you just get a Grid you can put whatever you like in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing the WinForms controls from Telerik. Their grid allows me to do what I've described above using the tabbed child templates.